# Polymer js 3.0 upgrade Uncaught TypeError: Polymer.dom is not a function

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x

I upgraded polymer 2.0 to polymer 3.0.
Now i am getting the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Polymer.dom is not a function" after updated the code using the modulizer tool.

```
var dateToday = new Date();
var currentYear = qy.helpers.formatTimeYear(dateToday); //is an string       
// currentYear = Number(currentYear);           

if (user.plan === 'advanced') {
 console.info("Advanced User");
 qy.userPlan = 'adv';
 var qyApp = document.createElement('qy-app'); // cargamos la app advanced
 //Polymer.dom(document.getElementById('app')).appendChild(qyApp);
 var d = document.getElementById('app');
 Polymer.dom(d).appendChild(qyApp);
} else {
 console.info("Profesional User");
 var qyApp = document.createElement('qy-app'); // cargamos la app for proffesional var qyApp = document.createElement('qy-appPR');
 qy.userPlan = 'pro';
 Polymer.dom(document.getElementById('app')).appendChild(qyApp);
```

Comment: Did you import `@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/polymer.dom.js`?

Comment: Yes i have done the following steps: 

import @polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/polymer.dom.js
and 
Refreshed cache in chrome. but the issue is still there.

Comment: Does `import {} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/polymer.dom.js'` change anything?

Comment: `import {dom} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/polymer.dom.js'` worked, then change `Polymer.dom` to `dom()`